Who are all these characters in this Ultimate Spider-Man poster?
I just found this Ultimate Spider-Man poster on Reddit:

Who are all these black-and-white characters in the background. I can only identify Venom.

The guy with the great big A on his forehead is Captain A. The Wolverine looking guy at the bottom is Dr Collossal. The guy with the Rhino horns is StinkWeevil

A nice homage to Amazing Spider-Man 100; https://static.wikia.nocookie.net/marveldatabase/images/e/e8/Amazing_Spider-Man_Vol_1_100.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20171229070139 featuring some of the same individuals, Kingpin, Dr. Doom, Venom, Doc Ock, The Lizard, etc etc



Harry Osborn/Hobgoblin (Earth-1610)
Wilson Fisk/Kingpin (Earth-1610)
Michael Morbius (Earth-1610)
Steven Grant/Moon Knight (Earth-1610)
Matt Murdock/Daredevil (Earth-1610)
Eddie Brock/Venom (Earth-1610)
Scorpion (Earth-1610)
Joseph/Hammerhead (Earth-1610)
Melvin Potter/Gladiator (Earth-1610)
Rhino (Earth-1610)
Kitty Pryde (Earth-1610)
J. Jonah Jameson (Earth-1610)
Carnage (Earth-1610)
Jonathan Storm/Human Torch (Earth-1610)
Blackie Drago/Vulture (Earth-1610)
Otto Octavius/Doctor Octopus (Earth-1610)
Mary Jane Watson (Earth-1610)
"Kong" Harlan (Earth-1610)
Ben Urich (Earth-1610)
"Flash" Thompson (Earth-1610)
Rose (Earth-1610)
Aunt May Parker (Earth-1610)
Herman Schultz/Shocker (Earth-1610)
Maxwell Dillon/Electro (Earth-1610)
Nick Fury (Earth-1610)
Ben Reilly (Earth-1610)
Norman Osborn/Green Goblin (Earth-1610)
Steve Rogers/Captain America (Earth-1610)
Jean DeWolff (Earth-1610)
Stephen Strange/Doctor Strange (Earth-1610)
James Howlett/Wolverine (Earth-1610)
Ben Grimm/Thing (Earth-1610)
Felicia Hardy/Black Cat (Earth-1610)


Comics.org identifies the characters on the variant cover as

Spider-Man [Peter Parker]; Hobgoblin [Harry Osborn]; Kingpin [Wilson
Fisk]; Moon Knight [Marc Spector; Steven Grant]; Daredevil [Matt
Murdock]; Venom [Eddie Brock Jr.]; Rhino; Kitty Pryde [Shadowcat];
Richard Parker; Carnage; Human Torch [Johnny Storm]; Dr. Octopus [Otto
Octavius]; Mary Jane Watson; Ben Urich; Aunt May Parker; General Nick
Fury; Green Goblin [Norman Osborn]; Wolverine [Logan]; Black Cat
[Felicia Hardy]; Captain America [Steve Rogers]; Captain Jeanne
Dewolfe; Dr. Strange; Thing [Ben Grimm]; Deadpool [Wadey Wilson];
Kraven the Hunter

